# Draw a vertical line separated by equal parts in Android

Tags: android, vertical-alignment, timeline, measurement

I want to draw a vertical line separated by equal parts(Like a Scale) in Android.
Please help me to make a vertical measuring scale..?

I can easily create a vertical line but to divide that in to several pieces is a task for me. can someone help on that and line will be a scrollable.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817123/android-putting-a-vertical-divider-separator-line-between-textviews-in-a-horizo    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128652/how-to-add-vertical-divider-to-a-horizontal-linearlayout

Comment: The above Links show vertical line only.I am familiar with this but I want to divide that vertical line in several equal parts like a measuring scale..

Answer (score 1):

use this for horizontal divider

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/honeycombish_blue" />
```

and this for vertical divider

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/honeycombish_blue" />
```

Comment: It creates vertical line only.I am familiar with this but I want to divide that vertical line in several equal parts like a measuring scale..